# File .form in GUI Swing java application

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

**Hi.**
I am newbie . i am learning Swing Java by IDEA.
I search some swing tutorials but they only code in class java . but some video they have a file *.form . What is that? how can i learn both swing + this form ?
Thanks

Comment: Learn Swing by using the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). If you use an IDE to create the GUI then you learn the IDE and not Swing and if you ever use a different IDE your code will not be portable to the other IDE.

Comment: In short what @camickr is trying to tell you that don't use IDE to create GUI rather learn it through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many form designer tools for swing to design a form by drag drop,

so when you will use such type of tools or plugin for designing a form then *.form file will generate automatically.

you can see JFormDesigner from https://www.formdev.com

Answer (score 0):

Form created by NetBeans, contains placement of GUI components for Java Swing  each file is devoted to a Java class  when a component is added to the formM file, a corresponding field is added in the connected class.